# How to display banner text inside the subshell along with the results of whatever is being run in subshell

Tags: command-line, subshell, motd

I'm trying to figure out how to display text inside a subshell along with the results of whatever is being run in the subshell, i.e: `test=$(sudo echo foo)`

I've already set up a `lecture_file` so that a message is displayed when the sudo command is run. I've also set up MOTD in `/etc/motd` so that a message is displayed when I ssh into my server. However, these do not get displayed or printed when a command is being run in the subshell

Comment: Can you elaborate? A subshell can display text and its result like this: `RESULT=123; echo "Goodbye - result is $RESULT"; exit $RESULT`. Your example assigns the string *foo* to the variable `test`. Why do you need `sudo`? What do you want to happen?

Comment: I think this is most the domain of the interactive shell. For bash, investigate the [PROMPT_COMMAND](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PROMPT_005fCOMMAND) variable, and the [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files)

Comment: @berndbausch I'm trying to debug a shellscript issue that a colleague ran into. She ran my shell script where I have the following line `result=$(sudo -u postgres -i psql/ ...)` My script will then do additional stuff depending on the result. However, it's breaking because I'm not accounting for the banner text that is in `result`. I'm not sure where it's coming from and I want to reproduce the problem on my environment. I thought the banner text was coming from a MOTD or sudoers lecture file, but I can't reproduce it

Comment: `sudo -i` does create a login shell, which could explain your banner. It may be generated by one of the profiles or other initialization files of user `postgres`. Most probably you can't reproduce it in your environment, because that user has a different environment on your colleague's server. The question I have: Why does the script need a login shell?

Comment: @berndbausch The script does not need a login shell. I intend to remove the -i flag. I'm just perplexed as to how the banner text gets generated and would like to reproduce it on my end. Could it be the `.bash_profile` file for the `postgres` user?

Comment: A login shell goes through all the initialization scripts, /etc/profile, .bash_profile, .bashrc, many more. One of them probably displays the banner.